# Gaussian Process Posterior

Tags: probability, bayesian, gaussian-process

while I was reading the article with the title of 'Variational Learning of inducing Variables in Sparse Gaussian Processes', author said that GP posterior can be written by like this.
[image]

I think it is correct to state $P(\mathbf z\mid \mathbf y) = \int p(\mathbf z\mid \mathbf f, \mathbf y)p(\mathbf f\mid \mathbf y)d  \mathbf f,$ and because f and y are not independent and f and z are not independent, i thought that z and y are not independent, so y is not ommitable.

Is there anybody who can help me to understand this?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_likelihood) should be helpful. If you're still confused from there, [start here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution). TLDR: independence does not matter when you marginalize a distribution.

Comment: I found out what i was missing. It was about the conditional independence! Anyway  i'm really appreciate of your attention for my question! Thanks